# Floating div element

Tags: html, css-position

I'd like to create a div element that is "floating", not in the sense of the [float property](http://w3schools.webmasterbeta.net/css/pr_class_float.asp), but rather literally "float":

[image]

Comment: The link to the "float property" is dead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`position: absolute` with a high enough `z-index`:

```
#element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a follow up to Tatu's answer, which will work, but uses z-indexes in a clumsy, but very common, way.

Z-index determines the stacking order of positioned elements, relative to other positioned elements. The stacking order is also relative to the stacking order of the parent elements. So:

When you have two sibling elements in a page:

```
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:2"></div><!-- Position 2 (top) -->
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1"></div><!-- Position 1 (bottom) -->
</body>
```

These are both stacked according to their parent - the `body`, which is at its default 'bottom' of the stack.

Now, when these elements have children with z-indexes, their position in the stack is determined relative to their parents' position:

```
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:2"><!-- Position 2 (top) -->
         <div style="position:absolute;z-index:2"></div><!-- Position 2.2 -->
         <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1"></div><!-- Position 2.1 -->
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1"><!-- Position 1 (bottom) -->
         <div style="position:absolute;z-index:2"></div><!-- Position 1.2 -->
         <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1"></div><!-- Position 1.1 -->
    </div>
</body>
```

I find it useful to think of the children as having a 'point' z-index - so the child of an element with `z-index:1` has a z-index of `1.x`. This way, you can see that, even if I give this div a z-index of 100000, it will never appear on top of an element with the parent z-index of 2. *2.x always appears on top of 1.x*

This is useful when you're making 'floating' things like overlays, post-it notes, etc. A setup like this is a good start:

```
<body>
    <div id="contentContainer" style="position:relative;z-index:1">
        All your 'page level content goes here. You can use all the z-indexes you like.
    </div>
   <div id="overlayContainer" style="position:relative;z-index:2">
        Anything to float 'on top of the page' goes here. Nothing inside 'contentContainer' can ever appear on top of it.
    </div>
</body>
```

Anything you want to float on top goes into 'overlayContainer' - the base z-indexes keep the two 'layers' separate, and you can avoid using confusingly high z-indexes like 999999 or 100000.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you need your CSS to look something like this

```
.floating-div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

Comment: If you're using really high z-indexes like that, you're probably not using them properly. Usually people use these as a way to say 'really, really, put this on the top', but then what happens if another element has 100001? See my 'answer' for code examples on a better way to manage z-indexes.

Comment: I agree completely, I was just typing 'large' to be obnoxiously clear as to the importance of the number being higher.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it using positioning and z-index;